# sed/awk string replacement with newline and tabs

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, xml

I have an XML file that contains the following:

```
<ipaddr>192.168.1.1</ipaddr>
    <subnet>24</subnet>
```

The goal is to modify `<ipaddr>192.168.1.1</ipaddr>` to `<ipaddr>192.168.1.125</ipaddr>` and `<subnet>24</subnet>` to `<subnet>25</subnet>` in one command. I do not want to change any other subnet tags inside the file.

The problem I have encountered is that there is a newline after `</ipaddr>` and there are two tabs before `<subnet>`.

I have tried this: `awk '{gsub (/<ipaddr>192.168.1.1<\/ipaddr>\n<subnet>24<\/subnet>/, "<ipaddr>192.168.1.125<\/ipaddr>\n\t\t<subnet>25<\/subnet>")}' config.xml` 
but it does not work.

Could someone guide me in the right direction for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to change the IP on one line and the sub-net on the next line:

```
 sed -E '/(192.168.1.)1/{s//\1125/; n; s/>24</>25</}' infile
```

That is not reporting any error if the IP is changed but the sub-net is not. Which seems to be what you want from your description.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Is n; the match for newline in this command?

Comment: Not exactly, `n` tells sed to read the next line from the file, then this line is matched. The end effect is that a newline must exist for this to match.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite incomplete a specification. What are we going to search for? Some generic pattern? The exact IP address, and exact subnet? If yes, try

```
$ sed -r '/(192.168.1.)1/{s//\1125/; N; s/24/25/}' file
<ipaddr>192.168.1.125</ipaddr>
          <subnet>25</subnet>
```

Comment: If the IP is changed to `124` it will be again changed to `125` by the next **s**ubstitution. Also, better use a limited subnet to be precise. Think what will hapen if the original subnet is 24 and the subnet change is `4` to `8` (for example). Finally, using `-E` is POSIX compliant (and portable).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data is a well formed XML document, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <ipaddr>192.168.1.2</ipaddr>
  <subnet>24</subnet>
  <ipaddr>192.168.1.1</ipaddr>
  <subnet>24</subnet>
</root>
```

The following XMLStarlet command would find the `ipaddr` node that has a current value of `192.168.1.1` and that whose first `subnet` sibling node is 24, and change that `ipaddr` node value to `192.168.1.125`.  It would then do a similar thing to change the `subnet` node's value to 25, using the new value of the `ipaddr` node to locate it.

```
xmlstarlet ed \
    -u '//ipaddr[. = "192.168.1.1" and following-sibling::subnet[1] = "24"]' -v '192.168.1.125' \
    -u '//subnet[. = "24" and preceding-sibling::ipaddr[1] = "192.168.1.125"]' -v 25 file.xml
```

The result would be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <ipaddr>192.168.1.2</ipaddr>
  <subnet>24</subnet>
  <ipaddr>192.168.1.125</ipaddr>
  <subnet>25</subnet>
</root>
```

The command would be a lot simpler and less error prone if the `ipaddr` and `subnet` nodes were child nodes of the same parent node, as in

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <host name="hostA">
    <ipaddr>192.168.1.2</ipaddr>
    <subnet>24</subnet>
  </host>
  <host name="hostB">
    <ipaddr>192.168.1.1</ipaddr>
    <subnet>24</subnet>
  </host>
</root>
```

Then we could simply select on the `host` node's name like so:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
    -u '//host[@name="hostB"]/ipaddr' -v '192.168.1.125' \
    -u '//host[@name="hostB"]/subnet' -v '25' file.xml
```

to produce

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <host name="hostA">
    <ipaddr>192.168.1.2</ipaddr>
    <subnet>24</subnet>
  </host>
  <host name="hostB">
    <ipaddr>192.168.1.125</ipaddr>
    <subnet>25</subnet>
  </host>
</root>
```